# Limit a meta box to a specific category

Tags: categories, metabox

I'm trying to limit a meta_box to posts in a specific category. I'm using this method: http://www.farinspace.com/page-specific-wordpress-meta-box/  and it works rather well But I can't seem to get it to work with categories. Heres' my code:

```
<?php 
// meta box for news category
add_action('admin_init','news_init');

function news_init(){

    $post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'] ;

    $post = get_post($post_id);

    if ($post->post_category == '6'){
    add_meta_box('news_details', 'News Details', 'news_details', 'post');
    }
}
?>
```

I feel like I'm missing a step. Thoughts or ideas?

Thank you,

Nadine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just went a different way on this, didn't end up using categories.

Comment: Could you explain why/how you made that decision, so future visitors will gain knowledge?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out his other post: http://www.farinspace.com/show-hide-meta-box-by-category/

I figure you would need some javascript because if you change categories, you would need some way for the browser to trigger to show the metabox, hence javascript.

He has a video tutorial, so that should help explain everything. Also, since you are already reading his blog, you might want to try out his `WPAlchemy_MetaBox` Class. I use it every time in my themes and I love it.

Comment: Yeah I can give that a shot, I looked it over before. re: the second post, but I'm just wondering if there's a more straight-forward way to do this using just a method of "find the Category ID of this post"

Answer (score 0):

`$post->post_category` is returning an Array
So you shoul tes like this

```
if ($post->post_category[0] == '6'){
   add_meta_box('news_details', 'News Details', 'news_details', 'post');
}
```